# Convert DWORD byte array to a unsigned long number

Tags: java, arrays, unsigned

I want the unsigned value of a little-endian DWORD byte array.

This is what I wrote:

```
private long getUnsignedInt(byte[] data) {
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result += (data[i] & 0xFF) << 8 * (data.length - 1 - i);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Is it right?

Comment: Does it give you the values you expect?

Comment: For what I tested yes, but I cannot understand if this is "two's complement" safe.

Comment: Nice downvoter, maybe I should not have post the code but only the question?

Comment: @Kayaman I mean "two's complement" (I was wrong and I edited my comment) representation for negative numbers

Comment: I know what two's complement is, but I have no idea what "two's complement" safe is supposed to mean. Especially if you're talking about unsigned numbers.

Comment: I want to get the right unsigned value from that dword, with xFFFFFFFF I don't want to get a value of -1 but 4294967295!

Comment: Okay, I understand what value you don't want to get. Now tell me, **do** you get that value?

Comment: No, I don't. Is this enought to say that is the right way for every negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I am afreaid that is big endian.

```
public long readUInt(byte[] data) {
    // If you want to tackle different lengths for little endian:
    //data = Arrays.copyOf(data, 4);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(data)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .getInt() & 0xFF_FF_FF_FFL;
}
```

The above does a 4 byte to (signed) int conversion and then make it unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

**Correted for BigEndian**

If by DWORD you mean 32 bits unsigned int, try this

```java
    public long readUInt(byte[] data) {
            return (
                ((long)(data[3] & 0xFF) << 24) |
                ((long)(data[2] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                ((long)(data[1] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                ((long)(data[0] & 0xFF) << 0));
    }
```

Joop Eggen's answer is correct, I think this one is faster as there is no object allocation.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote a loop because I wanted to be flexible for variable byte length, maybe I should check to do not exceed the length of long.

Comment: That is big-endian, not little-endian, as Joop also mentions in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39374621/5221149).

Comment: Yes you should invert shift values

Comment: Edited for BigEndian